# how to set back default UISegmentedControl appearance?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have set the appearance of UISegmentedControl using following code,

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment_Unselected.png"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment_Selected.png"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                           forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:45.0/255.0 blue:8.0/255.0 alpha:1],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                         [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                         [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentedControl_Divider.png"]
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and I got the perfect output 
[image]

but now I want to set default appearance of **UISegment** like
[image]

so what i have to do???

Comment: @BillWoodger I was just implementing this code, I did a change what I practically found and it was clearly visible in the code. It seems it's a copy-paste error. I know everyone who will try to use this code will eventually find the error, but I was just trying to save other's time :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger you're right. I should just have mentioned the problem in comment here. The wrong images are assigned to the `segmentSelected` and `segmentUnselected` variables above.

Comment: @AdilMalik You can always add it as an answer yourself. Answers are more visible than comments. If you edit the question, you may confuse future readers who wonder why the answers don't reflect the question (not necessarily in this example). I suggest you add an answer, then we can delete all these comments to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put this code on the viewcontroller that you want with default controller

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:nil]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:nil]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];
    
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                 forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:45.0/255.0 blue:8.0/255.0 alpha:1],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                 [UIColor clearColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,      
                                 [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                 [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] 
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal   
                                 rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 2):

remove code for images you have assigned.

Comment: but i want to use default segment for one view only, and for other i want custom segment ,,
i have return this code in rootviewcontroller of app, so how to reload default segment appearance ?

Comment: for other views leave the code as it is. For view with default segment you can use interface builder or add default segment by code.

Comment: i have try this in interface builder its show me default segment but when i run the app it shows me old appearance segment that is i have set early..
:(

Answer (score 1):

set imagename to nil on above code and put it on the view where you want default behavior

Answer (score 1):

Set the image of segment controller to nil . Then, once clean your simulator then run. It will be fine....